# didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not get called when scrolling and selecting a cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, scroll, didselectrowatindexpath

It seems when I scroll my table view that if I select a cell while the table view is still scrolling, didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called. It works fine when the table view is still.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Also, is there a way that didSelectRowAtIndexPath can be called on press down? It seems it gets called after my finger/cursor is raised off of the cell.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the correct behavior, while the tableView is scrolling the cells should not be interactive, otherwise tapping again to continue a long scroll would activate cells.

Comment: What if I want didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get called, even while scrolling is still going on. Is there a way I can accomplish this, even if that means putting scrolling to a halt forcefully so that didSelectRowAtIndexPath can get called?

Comment: I suppose that you could intercept the touch events when they come into your view, then determine where on the tableView they would be and call didSelectRowAtIndexPath: yourself... although I really think that it would provide a bad user experience. If you don't mind me asking, what is the use case?

Comment: I'm basically using two table views. One to display Categories and the other displays a list of information within each category. When selecting each different category, it instantly displays the information in the second table view, but if I scroll through the categories and then select one as its slowing, it doesn't display the information because didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called do to the still slightly scrolling.

Would be nice if I could find a way to get didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be called because it looks a bit buggy the way it works now, even if that is the correct behavior.

Comment: As I said before, you could intercept the touch events as they come into your main view and then handle everything yourself, but in your case I think breaking from the behavior that users know will probably feel a little more strange than having to wait for a table to stop scrolling.